# update cell value of duplicates without using for loop

Tags: pandas, duplicates

How can I get same results as the following code without using for loop: my typical data has ~500k rows, and as it is, the code is too time consuming.

```
data={'key1':[1,2,1,1,2,3,2,2],'key2':[2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2],'class':[5,10,'NaN','NaN','NaN',6,'NaN','NaN']}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['key1','key2','class'])
```

This dataframe contains some `[key1,key2]` duplicates, like: `[1,2]` and `[2,2]`.
The first occurence of the duplicate has a finite `'class'` value, whereas the other duplicates are assigned `'NaN' class` value. The following code takes the `'class'` value of the first occurence and assign it to the duplicates of same group.

```
for name, group in frame.groupby(['key1', 'key2']): 
    listOfIndex = group.index
    master_idx = listOfIndex[0]
    frame['class'].loc[listOfIndex] = frame['class'].loc[master_idx]



   key1  key2 class
0     1     2    5
1     2     2   10
2     1     2    5
3     1     2    5
4     2     2   10
5     3     4    6
6     2     2   10
7     2     2   10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by columns `key1` and `key2`, then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `NaN` to `np.nan`, [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by `ffill` in column `class` and last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for change `index` to original ordering:

Notice: Solution works if first value of duplicates in column `class` is **NOT** `NaN`.

```
df = frame.sort_values(by=['key1','key2'])
print df
   key1  key2 class
0     1     2     5
2     1     2   NaN
3     1     2   NaN
1     2     2    10
4     2     2   NaN
6     2     2   NaN
7     2     2   NaN
5     3     4     6

df['class'] = df['class'].replace('NaN', np.nan).fillna(method='ffill')

print df.sort_index()
   key1  key2  class
0     1     2    5.0
1     2     2   10.0
2     1     2    5.0
3     1     2    5.0
4     2     2   10.0
5     3     4    6.0
6     2     2   10.0
7     2     2   10.0
```

If values in column `class` are integers, cast by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['class'] = df['class'].replace('NaN', np.nan).fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
print df.sort_index()
   key1  key2  class
0     1     2      5
1     2     2     10
2     1     2      5
3     1     2      5
4     2     2     10
5     3     4      6
6     2     2     10
7     2     2     10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael. This is working nicely. I had to update pandas, because my version  did not have 'sort_values'